# How to write least significant bit into the buffer?

Tags: c++

I have a writeBit method that should write the least significant bit of int i into the buffer buff of type char and then increment the bit buffer index.
I am not sure if what I have is correct, any input is appreciated.

```
private:
char buff;    // buffer
int num_bits; // num of bits written to buff
std::ostream& os_ref;

public:
// Skipping the constructor and ostream& for brevity

int writeBit(int i) {
  // flush buffer if full
  if(num_bits == 8)
  flush();

  // write least significant bit into the buffer at the current index.
  int lb = i & 1;
  buff = buff & num_bits;  // not sure about this line
  buff = lb;
  num_bits++;

  // return current index
  return num_bits; // do I return nbits as current index?
}
```

Comment: have you tried it? what problem are you facing?

Comment: I can't try it until I write other methods so I wanted to know if what I have logically makes sense.

Comment: Where is `nbits` defined?

Comment: Sorry those should be num_bits.

Comment: buff = buff & nbits; buff = lb; these two lines together don't change anything

Comment: With buff = buff & num_bits; I was trying to write the least sig bit of i to the current index

Comment: 1) `flush()` means num_bits should reset to 0, 2) `buff = buff & num_bits;` why this is needed? logically the value will be present at 'num_bit` position of `buff`. Now `lb` is holding the value at 0th position. So you need to left shift it so 0s are padded to right of `lb` ( essentially, we are going to make the value of `lb` available at `num_bit`(th) position, and when it's done, we got `lb00..(n times)`. Now we `or` this to `buff` so the trailing zeroes does not have any effect just `lb` gets reflected at desired position (I just wrote what @Michael had done :P :P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess something like this *should* work, let me know :

```
buff |= (i & 1) << nbits;
```

Be sure that `buff` is set to 0 during `flush()`
Basically, `i & 1` get the last significant bit, `<< nbits` move the bit on the left *nbits* times and this bit is added to *buff*.

Comment: what does " << nbits" at the end do?

Comment: I think you need `nbits - 1` instead of `nbits`, because you always go slighty lefter as you want. `1 << 7` will set 8th byte, not 7th.

Comment: @Zaffy, no, that's what we want. If `nbits` is equal to 7, we want to set the 8th **bit** (not *byte* but it is a typo right?).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming flush sets num_bits to zero:

```
char unmask = ~(1 << num_bits);
buf &= unmask;
buf |= (i & 1) << num_bits;
++num_bits;
```

@Michael's answer is better, if the the bit at num_bits is always zero.

Answer (score 0):

To get the Least Significant Bit of an uint32_t:

```
uint32_t i = 1337;
uint8_t lsb = i & 1; // zeroes out all bits except first
buffer |= (lsb << num_bits); // shifts the lsb by num_bits to left and then ORs it into the char field
```

**Note:** I used `uint32_t` instead of `unsigned int` for compatibility reasons.

Comment: How is `uint32_t` more compatible than `unsigned int`?

Comment: `uint32_t` will always be 32 bits, while `unsigned int` is not guaranteed to be 32bits wide.

Comment: But `uint32_t` is C++11 only and is an _optional_ typedef. As you narrow into a `uint8_t` in the calculation you don't even need 32 bits. `unsigned int` is available in every C++ implementation, even pre-C++11 implementations. `uint32_t` is anything but more 'compatible' that `unsigned int`.

Comment: Yes, I know but I still think having the number of bits in the type is a good practice. If you don't like that, feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: I don't understand. Why is having the number of bits in a type a good practice? If you aren't relying on the exact number of bits in a type, why add an unnecessary constraint? (I don't really want to edit you post because I don't understand your reasoning, I just think you should expand on your note because just saying "compatibility reasons" doesn't really explain your argument.)

Comment: Like in this case, you have to do work with bits, isn't it better to see instantly how many bits are there in a specific type? I do understand that in everyday programming where you don't need to know the exact number of bits, it is an overkill. I got this practice on myself when I was developing a kernel, and there it was very important to know exactly how long was everything. It might be just a bad side-effect of low-level programming recently, but honestly I think it is better.